# AngularJSのフィルターの検索条件を頭文字や語尾に限定

Tags: angularjs

AngularJSのフィルタ機能についての質問です。

"12345"
"23456"
"34567"
"45678"

という文字列があった場合「45」を入力すると全て引っかかってしまうのですが、
頭文字のみの検索だった場合"45678"のみが表示され
語尾のみの検索だった場合"12345"のみが表示されるように設定することは可能でしょうか？

自分なりに検索して探したのですが、見つからなかったのでこちらで質問させていただきます。

Answer (score 1):

カスタムフィルターを作り正規表現を使えるようにしてみてはいかがですか?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046928/how-to-use-regex-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs

ここにあるregexフィルターなんてどうですか?